# why descending / ascending icon direction on differs on windows vs. linux?

Tags: linux, windows, user-experience

Which up/down icons indicate the sort direction of a column in a table?

I need to add such icons to my website tables, but from what I've seen the symbol is in windows in the opposite from linux.

the first screenshot is taken from "total-commander" (windows), while the other is a typical Linux file manager.

so, in everywhere in windows, a down arrow indicates DESCending order, and on linux Asscending.  Clearly (to me) the windows solution looks correct.

So why was it chosen to be different in all linux programs?  Which icons should I use on my website, and WHY?

[image]

[image: a linux program]

Comment: I don't think there's one true "correct" way. It's a matter of conventions, and conventions differ. Besides, the timestamps in your first screenshot are not even sorted (look at the first four).

Comment: ah, thanks (only folders weren't sorted - fixed the screenshot)